# Calendar.before() and Calendar.after() returning incorrect values

Tags: java, android, calendar

I'm getting a bit stuck with date comparison in Java/Android

```
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm");
                Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
                Calendar c;

                c = Calendar.getInstance();
                c.set(settings.getInt("year", 0), settings.getInt("month", 0), settings.getInt("day", 0), settings.getInt("hour", 0), settings.getInt("minute", 0));

                views.setTextViewText(R.id.textView4, String.valueOf(c.getTime().before(now.getTime())));
                views.setTextViewText(R.id.textView2, String.format("%s - %s", df.format(c.getTime()), df.format(now.getTime())));

                int timeout = 0;
                while( c.getTime().before(now.getTime()) )
                {
                    c.add(Calendar.SECOND, 30);
                    c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 12);
                    c.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 6);
                    isHigh = 1 - isHigh;
                    timeout++;
                    if( timeout >= 400 )
                        break;
                }
                views.setTextViewText(R.id.textView5, String.valueOf(c.getTime().before(now.getTime())));
                views.setTextViewText(R.id.textView3, String.format("%s - %s", df.format(c.getTime()), df.format(now.getTime())));
```

The idea of this is it takes a starting date from saved settings, and adds 6:12:30 to the clock until it passes the current time.

However, my textboxes give me the following:

> false : 09/07/12 04:20 - 11/08/12 00:00
>
> false : 09/07/12 04:20 - 11/08/12 00:00

Why is 9th July 2012 returning false when calling "before(11th Aug 2012)"?

If I change the ".before" to ".after", I get this:

> true : 09/07/12 04:20 - 11/08/12 00:00
>
> true : 20/10/12 15:40 - 11/08/12 00:00

Which doesn't seem to make any sense.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Try to logCat the two Dates before you compare them and post the result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wonder whether it's because your "year" setting is 12 rather than 2012. Then you'd be comparing 09/07/2012 with 11/08/0012 - but you can't tell because of your date format.

For diagnostic purposes, change your format string to `"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"` and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Well, its working as expected in JDK with 12 as well as 2012.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm");
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar c;
c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(12, 6, 9, 0, 0);
System.out.println(String.valueOf(c.getTime().before(now.getTime()))); 
System.out.println(String.format("%s - %s", df.format(c.getTime()), df.format(now.getTime())));
```

Output:-
true
09/07/12 00:00 - 11/08/12 13:29

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue earlier. But I was not required to compare hours, minutes and seconds. Only date. But @Jon Skeet's answer not worked for me. So I've implemented my own method for compare two dates. **Ugly**, but works fine.

```
private boolean before(Calendar c1, Calendar c2){
        int c1Year = c1.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int c1Month = c1.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int c1Day = c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        int c2Year = c2.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int c2Month = c2.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int c2Day = c2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        if(c1Year<c2Year){
            return true;
        }else if (c1Year>c2Year){
            return false;
        }else{
            if(c1Month>c2Month){
                return false;
            }else if(c1Month<c2Month){
                return true;
            }else{
                if(c1Day<c2Day){
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```